# Next / Last Edited Position Eclipse Shortcut - And Netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I remember in Eclipse there were buttons in the toolbar that took you to the last edited position in a document.

This was great cause you could write some code, click on a method to go check out the code there, and then click "back" to get back to where you were coding.

Any idea if this can be done in Netbeans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, it's unbound by default but you find the setting in `Tools -> Options -> KeyMap`. Search for `last` for instance to find the setting.